# 'laid out on three levels of elevation 20 feet in height' Help me understand this phrase

Tags: phrase-meaning, ambiguity, sentence-meaning

The following is the description of the camp. I cannot imagine what it is, because of the ambiguity of the underlined part. The wooden building is 20 feet high? Could anyone be kind enough to explain it for me?

> The camp was constructed entirely of one story, wooden building, *laid out on three levels of elevation 20 feet in height*, connected by wooden stairways.

Comment: Could this be a typo for _wooden buildings_? (i.e. there were many single-story buildings on three levels.)

Comment: I think it should read: building (singular). Excerpt is from: ( http://www.mansell.com/pow_resources/camplists/osaka/narumi/nag_02b_narumi_SCAP%20report.html ) It is confusing, but the camp itself may have been one large warehouse etc. as the following paragraph suggests there were two-story barracks attached to the (singular) building?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The single-storey  building is constructed on ground of different height or [**elevation**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/elevation), and so the sections needed to be connected by stairs.

> **elevation**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> Height above a given level, especially sea level.
> *Line of sight and terrain elevation is very important!*

The ground level varies by 20 feet in height. Something *like* (but not exactly) this:

[image]

<sub>*Copyright [ArchDaily](https://www.archdaily.com/900844/split-level-homes-50-floor-plan-examples)*</sub>